# could not find app configuration tab when trying to deploy bot in teams

Tags: c#, .net, azure, bots

[image: Configure Tab bot in Teams]

when i am trying to configure tab in teams channel,i followed the steps from article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio  i could not find selection of tab and save button enabled , why this happned? how to solve it?, I am using echo bot template which is running on bot emulator properly.
Following is the json

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "2fac8fdd-7fa3-451f-8562-adba3ab84c8d",
    "packageName": "com.contoso.helloworld",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Hello World App ",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "janApp",
        "full": "janApp"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "SWAN Bot App for Microsoft Teams",
        "full": "This sample app provides a very simple app for Microsoft Teams. You can extend this to add more content and capabilities."
    },
    "accentColor": "#A4D344",
    "configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "https://echobot57.azurewebsites.net/configure",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "com.contoso.helloworld.hellotab",
            "name": "Botdemo",
            "contentUrl": "https://echobot57.azurewebsites.net/hello",
            "websiteUrl": "https://echobot57.azurewebsites.net/hello",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "330b4c4d-5f92-4053-a38f-7d4593cfd18a",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": true,
            "isNotificationOnly": true
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "330b4c4d-5f92-4053-a38f-7d4593cfd18a",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "getRandomText",
                    "type": "query",
                    "title": "Get some random text for fun",
                    "description": "Gets some random text and images",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "fetchTask": false,
                    "context": [
                        "commandBox",
                        "compose",
                        "message"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "cardTitle",
                            "title": "Card title",
                            "description": "Card title to use",
                            "inputType": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "echobot57.azurewebsites.net"
    ]
}
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the tab configuration url is correct.

[image]

If it is correct, you should be able to access it.

```
https://microsoftteamssampleshelloworldweb20200107021253.azurewebsites.net/configure
```

[image]